# Controllers and pages without "actions"? MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web

As I understand it the "MVC" came before the web and is often used in Desktop software for example.

If I understand correctly, the *Controller* runs at the time that the user will click a button and this will trigger an action.

But if we talk about web pages, the scenario is a little different, assuming the user clicks a link then it triggers an action.

But then, came me the doubt, is the *home* page part of a *Controller*?

What I mean is, the homepage is not usually performed by a user action within the website is just the *home*, but noticed that many PHP frameworks use a *Controller* for the *home*, is that correct?

Another doubt is in my *"home"* I have several items, for example:

- banners
- featured posts
- recent posts

Each of these items would have a different *Model*, can I call more than one *Model* and a *View* into the *Controller*?

Would these be the correct steps? Or most of php frameworks are not strict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely right and I understand the confusion.

**In a pure MVC approach**, the Controller only listens to user actions and updates the Model accordingly. The Model then notifies the View (through the Observer design pattern) and the View updates itself, accessing the data it needs from the Model.
This is how it was done before the web, in desktop application, where the Model and the View are running concurrently, and where the Model can notify the View. The Controller doesn't set up the View.

In this pure MVC model, the example you mentioned about the *homepage* doesn't need a Controller indeed. The View would just render itself, accessing the data it needs through the Model. Controllers are very thin and only listen to user actions and update the Model. That's all they do.

**In the web**, this model is not possible, and thus there are alternative approaches. The Model can't notify the View as in the pure model, and thus what popular frameworks require you to do, is to set up the View in your Controller. That's why for your example of the *homepage* you **need** a Controller, as you will set up your view there with all the data it requires.

**However**, there is another approach I have been personally writing about, where Controllers don't set up the View which allow you to keep tiny Controllers. You can read about it here: [A better OOP approach to building MVC applications](http://gobline.com/docs/concepts/mvc/controller)

Thus I believe that the *homepage* shouldn't need a controller action at all. The View should just render itself and access the data it needs to render. The Controller's role is to handle user actions and update the model accordingly, as you said. If it does more than that, it probably violates SRP. The Controller shouldn't set up the View, instead, [the View should get its own data from the Model](http://gobline.com/docs/concepts/mvc/view).